# How to access secure website with Fiddler autoresponder enabled?

Tags: windows, https, fiddler

I am on Win 10.  If I enable Fiddler autoresponder I cannot access any secure website.

Here is Chrome error:

[image]

Here is Firefox error:

[image]

How to access secure website with Fiddler autoresponder enabled?

Comment: [Decrypting HTTPS-protected traffic](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) - "Can I reconfigure my Windows client to trust the Fiddler root certificate to avoid error messages in IE and Chrome, as well as enabling logon to services like LiveID, etc?"

Comment: @DavidPostill I did exact same thing before asking and it didn't work.  Later I again went to the configuration and in really small font  it said: "Changes may not take effect until Fiddler restarted".  I restarted Fiddler and it is working now.  Thanks.   This is fixed. ( Chrome is working now, FF still have the problem. But I can live with that )

Comment: Great. Answer added. I've added instructions for Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I access secure website with Fiddler autoresponder enabled?

You need to  trust the Fiddler root certificate.

---

#### Can I reconfigure my Windows client to trust the Fiddler root certificate

> 1. When you tick the "Decrypt HTTPS Traffic" checkbox in Fiddler 2.2.9+, you will see the following prompt:
>
>    [image: Trust Prompt]
> 2. If you click Yes, you will see the following prompt:
>
>    [image: Windows Trust Prompt]
> 3. If you click "Yes" then Windows will trust your Fiddler Root certificate and certificate warnings will be suppressed in any
>      application which relies upon the Windows Certificate Store.

Note:

- You must restart Fiddler for the changes to take effect.

Source [Decrypting HTTPS-protected traffic](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)

#### How do I configure Firefox to trust the Fiddler root certificate?

> 1. Open Fiddler 2.2.9+. Click Tools > Fiddler Options. Select the HTTPS tab, and click the Export Fiddler Root Certificate to Desktop
>      button.
> 2. In Firefox, click Tools > Options....
> 3. Click the Advanced button at the top.
> 4. Click the Encryption tab.
> 5. Click View Certificates.
> 6. Click the Authorities tab.
> 7. Click Import. Pick the .CER file from your desktop.
> 8. Check the "Trust this CA to identify web sites" checkbox.
> 9. Click OK.
>
>    [image: Trust Certificate UI]

Source [Decrypting HTTPS-protected traffic](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)